# How do I create a folder structure inside a view

Tags: views, 8

I have created a view to get the all images that I have used in the website.  But it returns as a bulk list. But I have saved the images according to a folder structure. How do I get the images according to a folder structure in my view.

Below is my view

[image]

Currently it returns a bulk list. How do I get the images with the folder structure?

For an example I need to get the /path1/path2/image.jpg inside a folder named path1 which contains a folder named path2.

Comment: By concept views are always flat lists. You cannot generate tree structures with views.

Answer (score 0):

The feature "Group by field" provides a hierarchy, but you don't have the path components out of the box.

Are you using a module that is controlling the paths that is also integrated with views, maybe File field paths? If you can get a field to display a path component you will be able to group by them, effectively getting a folder structure.

[Views tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) also helps, if you have the path components.

This comparison list might help: [File Uploading and Managing](https://groups.drupal.org/node/20291).

If no module provides this already you'll have to create your own Views Field formatter for the file URL link field and use with some hierarchy mentioned above, or create a completely new Views Format for the File Views type that displays results in a hierarchy.